# Test design for taking screenshot with Selenium WebDriver on failed JUnit tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, junit4

I'm running into a strange JUnit and Selenium issue. 
I want to write a screenshot taker that will take a screenshot on failed tests.

I define the screenshot taker class as:

```
public class SeleniumJUnitScreenshotTaker implements MethodRule
{
private WebDriver driverLocal;


public SeleniumJUnitScreenshotTaker(WebDriver driver)
{
    driverLocal = driver;
}


public void takeScreenshot(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        new File("test-results/scrshots/").mkdirs(); // Make sure directory is there
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test-results/scrshots/" + fileName + ".png");
        out.write(((TakesScreenshot) driverLocal).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // No need to crash the tests here
    }
}


public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final FrameworkMethod frameworkMethod, final Object o)
{
    return new Statement()
    {
        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable
        {
            try
            {
                statement.evaluate();
            }
            catch (Throwable t)
            {
                takeScreenshot(frameworkMethod.getName());
                throw t; // rethrow
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I've a base test class where I setup the WebDriver as follows:

```
public class TestBase
{
protected static WebDriver driver;

@Rule
public SeleniumJUnitScreenshotTaker seleniumJUnitScreenshotTaker = new SeleniumJUnitScreenshotTaker(driver);

.
.
.

@BeforeClass
public static void intialize() 
{
    .
    .
    driver = SeleniumWebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(browser.toString());


    if ((browser != Browser.Chrome) && (browser != Browser.ChromeCanary))
    {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    hostUrl = Configuration.getHostUrl(envUnderTest);
    // Open Browser and navigate to main page
    driver.navigate().to(hostUrl);
}


@Before
protected void setup() throws Exception
{
    this.users = getUsers();
}


@After
protected void teardown()
{
    this.testCases.cleanupChecks();
}


@AfterClass
public static void terminate()
{
    // Shut down WebDriver
    if (driver != null)
        driver.quit();
    SeleniumWebDriverFactory.stopDriverService();
}
}
```

The problem is when I try to run a series of tests in the test class (derived from TestBase), the tests after the first failure throws TimeoutException. This is because we don't close the current browser between tests and the new test tries to find things that are absent in current browser. 
Is there a way to close browser in between tests but not close the driver? Or reinstantiate the driver between tests? Else is there an alt. design that can make this work?

Thanks

Yana

Comment: Without getting into how or why you chose this design, reassigning the `driver` every time a test method is invoked can't be all that tough - you just do it in the `@Before` annotated `setup` method.

Comment: A [`driver.close`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#close%28%29) in the `@After` annotated `teardown` method might also help.